# Formal Grammar removing unit production

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

Assume that I have 2 productions X and Y.

> X-> AL|BL|X,
>
> Y-> CK|DK|X.

I guess is not possible to reduce unit productions in X, but is this the case for Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the unit production X → X as it has no effect - expanding X → X in any derivation can be removed and replaced by using one of the other X productions.

Having done that, you can then remove all unit productions for Y by replacing Y → X with Y → ω for each remaining production X → ω.